# Automatically save data to file at certain time from web page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a webpage and I am getting data from a database. I was wondering if there was a way that at a specific time (say 6:00pm) I can automatically run a SQL query and save the data in a file on the site, without any user interaction.

I would use this to display data in a graph.

I am using phpMyAdmin for my database, and am familiar with PHP, MySQLi, javascript and jQuery.

I appreciate that this may be a bit of a weird question.

EDIT: The server is hosted on linux

Comment: You can define event listener at `phpMyAdmin` page. See [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T94c7.png).

Comment: u could use ajax to check if the time is 6 pm, or u can make a function with jquery and when the time gets 6 then send the values from the file with ajax

Comment: cron job, run script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on linux it is very common to use cron for such a task. Simply run

```
[vim|vi|nano|whatever] crontab -e
```

And create the task. You will need the PHP script to get the data and ensure you can execute it like

```
php [/path/to/script/]script.php
```

Then set your schedule and it will work

Crontab examples http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples

To save data to a file you could take the result (if using SQL most likely an array) you could do something like

```
$result = $PDO->query($Query)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
file_put_contents([file].json, json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This will make a json file that will have the query result. Your javascript can pull it or you can serve it with PHP like an API. This will also overwrite the old data every time it runs.

Comment: Wouldn't this work? OP would write a script to execute the query and save the array to a file accessible via the web server.. editing to add that step

Comment: The file will just store all of the data, and then when the user goes on the page I can read from it and display it

Comment: Offcourse it will work, but what if the file that OP ask is a test file and he wants when the time be 6pm all the values that the student has insert in the form to automaticly insert in the table.. Thats why i'am telling...

Comment: Edit added. It will print out a JSON file to the file specified. that should accomplish the task

Comment: I got the script and it works, but how do i get to run at 6pm every day?

Comment: via crontab command: 

[ 0 18 * * * php [path/to/script/]script.php >> /tmp/script.log  2>&1 ]

This should run the script at the time and output any text to a log as well

Comment: yes. you will add it to the bottom of the file that opens. then save & exit (ctrl + X then yes if nano) if you have any errors in syntax it will tell you

Comment: can I open this file anywhere or does it have to be at root?

Comment: No you can do it as you. If you can execute the script as you. I wouldn't recommend adding to the root crontab if you don't have to since it would run the task as root.

Comment: When i define my path to the script where do i start from?

Answer (score 0):

you should use cron jobs. [How to create a cron job in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)

then you can create a php page and run it in a command in your cron job like:

```
php /path/to/myCronJob.php
```